# "well" to express a possibility

Tags: adverbs

I would like to know if **both of the following** are correct, especially if the `2` is correct.

We are talking about the possibility that that task may be assigned to me

> 1. That task could be very well assigned to me
> 2. That task could be well assigned to me

Comment: `The task could well be assigned to me`, is probably what you meant.

Comment: Yes, in both cases the common phrasing is “...could (very) well be...”. It's the “could be” that expresses the possibility, and the “well” or “very well” modifies “be” to communicate an increase in certainty that the possibility will come to **be.** Hopefully someone with a more nuanced sense of the grammar in play will give you a full-fledged answer.

Comment: Yes, definitely move *well* and *very well* before *be*.

Comment: The use of *could be* suggests that the task *may be* assigned to you. What about the third possibility - *Well, the task could be assigned to me.* This seems better to me.

Comment: @MaulikV Your example uses *well* as a [discourse marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker), so the sentence doesn't have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

They are not correct as written--well, they are actually grammatically correct--but it's just a minor syntax issue that misconstrues the meaning. As you've written them, they, in reality, mean something different from what you'd intended to say, which I'll explain in a bit.

As the commentators have suggested so far, it should read more like this:

That task **could very well be** <del>very well</del> assigned to me

That task **could well be** <del>well</del> assigned to me.

First of all, yes, you absolutely can omit *very*. It's just an intensifier, and intensifiers are only required for emphasis. When you remove *very*, you make the likelihood less certain. But it's still grammatically correct.

Second, in these examples, as you seem to be aware, [well](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well?show=0&t=1386445077) is the equivalent of definition number *10b* under the adverbial definition. In [this](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/well%5B1%5D) source, it's definition number *4b*.

Now, as for the way these sentences were originally constructed, that would mean that it'd be a *wise choice* to assign the task to that person.

> That task **would** *[could]* be **[very] well *(i.e., properly)* assigned** to me.

In the first set of examples, *well* means *likely* or *possibly*. In my last example, it means that it'd be a *good decision* to assign the task to that person.

All of these are examples of speculation in the subjunctive mood.